# Intervention Image make() doesn't work on Laravel console kernel schedule with larger files

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, intervention

I have a schedule on my `console\kernel.php` like this:

```
$client = new Client;
// I use GuzzleHttp\Client because I can't turn `allow_url_fopen` on
$response = $client->get($image_url);
$body = $response->getBody();
$str = (string) $body;
$image = Image::make($str);
```

It works well with smaller images (~<200KB), but on files with ~>200KB, the last line crashes without any error logs.

I also tried to get `strlen($str)` to compare its length with remote file's bytes right before `$image = Image::make($str);`. it was okay even with a file with `898,357 bytes` size and returned `898357`.

I tried to use this code in `web.php` to debug in this way:

```
$client = new Client;
$response = $client->get($image_url);
$body = $response->getBody();
$str = (string) $body;
$image = Image::make($str);
return  $image->response('jpg', 70);
```

It works well even with large images, but in this way:

```
$client = new Client;
$response = $client->get($image_url);
$body = $response->getBody();
$str = (string) $body;
$image = Image::make($str);
return  $image->response();
```

It just responses for small files and crashes on large files.

Are there any ways to fix this?

Comment: make sure to check `memory_limit` in php.ini. try to increase it and restart server and debug again.

Comment: @Kul my project is on a shared hosting service, so i can't.

Comment: @Pourbahrami sure you can; write an email to the provider.

Comment: @Kul @Kyslik I tried `ini_get('memory_limit');` and it returned `32M`. I think it must be enough memory limit to handle it.